# What does @ mean in php@7.2 in `brew list`

Tags: php, homebrew

I am having some issues when upgrading an applications php framework. Exploring different theories... Now I want to make sure that I am just using one PHP version.

When I do `brew list` I see one plain **php** and then I also have **php@7.2** - what does this mean?

Comment: It looks like a version number.

Comment: version ... it can be @7.2  7.3  7.4 ...

Answer (score 0):

This is a versioned formula (package). While `php` will always be of the latest version, `php@7.2` will always be at `7.2`.

Versioned formulæ aren’t symlinked by default because they are alternate versions. You must either force-link them (using `brew link --force`) or alter your `PATH` to use them.

You can run `which -a php` to see all the `php` executables in your `PATH`.